# How to display uploaded files in an apache server

Tags: apache-http-server

So, i've recently installed Apache HTTP server on my MacOS Mojave computer. When I go to my own IP, it displays the "it works!" page. However, what I want is apache to display my files in a specific directory. I don't have a web control panel. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these two lines in 'Apache24\conf\httpd.conf' file

```
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
```

Change "${SRVROOT}/htdocs" according to your requirement. For example, I have changed them  to "d:/root" and it now looks like

```
DocumentRoot "d:/root"
<Directory "d:/root">
```

Comment: Where is the folder "Apache24"?

Comment: It is the folder where apache is installed. I use windows. Google search showed, it's in the /etc folder and named as apache2.

Comment: After revisiting this question, I found out that this answer doesn't answer my question. My main question was “what I want is apache to display my files in a specific directory”

Comment: I also changed the title to avoid confusion